# Jasmine console not showing any colors when used with protractorjasmine2 html reporter

Tags: configuration, jasmine, protractor

Protractor conf.js:
This isn't showing any colors on my console.
I have added all required configs, but still no color output

I am trying to use a reporter here to print all browser reports here.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
var timeStamp=moment().format("MMDDYY_HHmmss");


exports.config = {

    // ----- Connect to Browser Drivers ------------------------------------------
    debugMode: true,
    directConnect: true,
    chromeDriver: 'C:/Users/LJQAuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.43.exe',
    firefoxPath: 'C:/Users/LJQAuser/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.1',
    //seleniumServer
   // seleniumAddress: 'http://192.168.99.100:4445/wd/hub',
   // seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar',
    //seleniumAddress: 'http://192.168.99.100:4447/wd/hub',
  /*  webDriverStart: {
        args: ['--seleniumPort', '4455']
    },*/
    noGlobals: false,

    //seleniumArgs: ['--proxy=http://xxx:8080', '-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom'],
   /* suites: {
        regressionSuite: ['spec/!*kioskSampleWithCache*.js']//will run all specs in subfolders
    },*/
    // Spec patterns are relative to the location of this config.
    specs: [
       //  'spec/WEB*145*.spec.js',
         'spec/sprint4/*415*.spec.js',
        // 'spec/sprint5/*.spec.js',
       //  'spec/sprint6/*.spec.js',
       //  'spec/sprint7/*.spec.js',
         //'spec/DB/*.spec.js',
      /*   'spec/WEB-146.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-147.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-148.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-149.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-163.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-164.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-165.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-166.spec.js',
         'spec/WEB-196.spec.js',*/
       //  'spec/WEB-329.spec.js',

    ],
    exclude: [
        'spec/WEB*147*.spec.js',
        'spec/WEB*148*.spec.js',
        'spec/WEB*186*.spec.js',
        'spec/WEB*192*.spec.js',
    ],

    // ----- Set up browsers -----------------------------------------------------
   /* capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'idle-duration':10000,
      /!*  'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--user-data-dir=/a/random/path']
        }*!/

    },*/

    multiCapabilities: [
        {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'idle-duration':10000,
    }, {
        'browserName': 'firefox',
            'marionette': true,
        "moz:firefoxOptions": {
            "binary": "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox"
        //    "binary": "C:/Firefox Installer.exe"
        },
        'idle-duration':10000,
    }],
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        showQuicklink: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000
    },

    params: {

        max_wait_for_notification_popup:4000,
        browserWidth:1080,
        browserHeight:1920
    },


    // ----- Set up Runner, reporters -----------------------------------------------------
    // TIMEOUTS
    // https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md
    // getPageTimeout: 60000, // Waiting for (Angular on) Page to Load
       allScriptsTimeout: 120000, // Waiting for Angular AND   Asynchronous Script Timeout
    // browser.ignoreSynchronization // to disable waiting for Angular

    //resultJsonOutputFile:'result.json',
    restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,

    useAllAngular4AppRoots: true,

    onPrepare: function () {
     //   var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
        return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
            browser.getCapabilities().then(function(value) {
                reportName = 'protractor-report-' + '_' + value.get('browserName') + '_' + Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16);
                jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
                    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                        savePath: __dirname+'/target',
                        docTitle: 'Web UI Test Report',
                        screenshotsFolder: '/image',
                        //takeScreenshots: true,
                        takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
                        consolidate: true,
                        consolidateAll: true,
                        preserveDirectory: true,
                        cleanDestination: false,
                        showColors:true,
                        //fixedScreenshotName: true,
                        fileName: "my-report.html",
                        fileNamePrefix: reportName
                    })
                );
                fulfill();
            });
        });
    },



    // Close the report after all tests finish


    afterLaunch: function afterLaunch() {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var output = '';
        fs.readdirSync('target/').forEach(function (file) {
            if (!(fs.lstatSync('target/' + file).isDirectory()))
                output = output + fs.readFileSync('target/' + file);
        });
        fs.writeFileSync('target/Consolidated-Report.html', output, 'utf8');

    },

    };
```

I will post the console output here as well.
please have a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine2HtmlReporter is a html reporter, means it generate an html report with information from the test.

As i read the description of this framework, it does not support console logs.
**showcolors** propertie is not an option inside this framework.
https://github.com/Kenzitron/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter#readme

If you wish a console output, uncomment the **jasmine-spec-reporter**
and register it to jasmine.

Ref to framework github page: https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter

Comment: But I have added jasmine's node options i.e                                             jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,  // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        isVerbose: true,
        realtimeFailure: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
        //pageLoadTimeout:120000,
       // print: function() {},                                                                                            
           // Function called to print jasmine results., why can't it show better console now.

Comment: please have a look at my comment above.

Comment: showcolors is to display test results colored. Ex: failed in red, success in green

Comment: But it's not working, My motive is to get reporting of 2 browsers simultaneously with proper console logs, which i am not getting through this config file.I am only getting reporting correct for 2 browsers, but console logs are not showing any colors and no links for errors are displayed, debugging is tough.